# Why does "mps" device perform worse in backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I am still relatively a beginner in PyTorch. I tried to use the GPU of my m1 macbook air for training by transferring all my tensors on "mps" device, but it performed worse in backpropagation than when I ran it on the CPU.

I tried to test the GPU performance on the following smaller problem:

```
import torch
import time
device = torch.device("mps")

x = torch.rand((10000,10000), device = device, requires_grad = True)
y = torch.rand((10000,10000), device = device, requires_grad = True)

loss = (x @ y).sum()
init = time.time()
loss.backward()
fin = time.time()
gpu = fin - init
print(gpu)

a = torch.rand((10000,10000), device = 'cpu', requires_grad = True)
b = torch.rand((10000,10000), device = 'cpu', requires_grad = True)

l = (a @ b).sum()
init = time.time()
l.backward()
fin = time.time()
cpu = fin - init
print(cpu)
```

and this outputs the following:

```
0.028150081634521484
0.0022008419036865234
```

I don't understand how my CPU outperforms my GPU on bakcprobagation.

Note: I tried using "mps" for a bigger model on the MNIST dataset and it was significantly slower than the CPU. I tried the same code on a "cuda" device and it performed better than the CPU.